# how to create an array of maps in flutter for dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to send data from my flutter app to my node.js server in the format below

```
var schema = [
  {name: 'Name', type: 'STRING'},
  {name: 'Age', type: 'INTEGER'},
  {name: 'Weight', type: 'FLOAT'},
  {name: 'IsMagic', type: 'BOOLEAN'},
];
```

but I cant seem to figure out how, my first attempt was to create an object and then add the objects to an array, my approach is below

```
 var newObject =
              dataObject(
                name: listA[i],
                type: listB[i]);
 var jsonOb = jsonEncode(newObject);

 data.add(jsonOb);
```

but its not working, any solutions to this?

Comment: What object are you trying to send exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You must transform to json before sending.